# Use Date column or insert a new index column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting financial data from Yahoo. Problem is that I am trying to plot a graph using the date column as the X axis and price column as the y axis but Python hates dates and is having NONE of it.

1st question: Is there any way to use the Date column for the x-axis?

2nd question: How do I insert a numbered index column into the dataframe which I can use to plot this data?

The error:

```
---> 23 Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(x)    
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

My code:

```
# Import yfinance
import yfinance as yf  
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Get the data for the stock Apple by specifying the stock ticker, start date, and end date
df = yf.download('EURUSD=X','2019-11-01','2019-12-01')

df = df.loc['2019/11/5':'2019/12/30']
df = df.head(20)
df = df[['High','Low']]
df['High_Low_Mean'] = df['High'] - df['Low']
x = df.index.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
y = df.iloc[:, 2].values.reshape(-1, 1)

print(df)

linear_regressor = LinearRegression()  # create object for the linearregression class
linear_regressor.fit(x,y)
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(x)


fig, (ax) = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
#fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(20,15)) #create 2 subplots

ax = plt.subplot("211")
#ax2 = plt.subplot("212")

ax.scatter(x,y,color='purple')
ax.plot(x, Y_pred, color='red')
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=25)
ax.set_xlabel('Interval', fontsize=25)
ax.set_title('Mean reversion of Close Prices',fontsize= 45,color='white')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('white')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('white')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='White',labelsize=20)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='White', labelsize=20)
plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.03, 1, 1.2]) #layout to make it fit nicely
```

Comment: see Series.plot and df.plot

Comment: to answer 2: Order your dataframe by the date and use the Counter variable in your prediction 
    df.sort_values('Date')

    df['counter'] = range(len(df))

Answer (score 0):

You can reset index and convert the datetime column to a datetime object. This makes plotting with matplotlib really easy.

```
basket=['AAPL','COST','BAC','SNXFX','VTEB','FNDX']

for ticker in basket:
    response=requests.get('http://www.alphavantage.co/query? 
function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol= {}&outputsize=compact&apikey=<your key>'.format(ticker))
    data=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response.json()['Time Series (Daily)'],orient='index')
    data=data.reset_index()
    data.columns=['Date','open','high','low','close','volume']
    data=data.sort_values(by=['Date'])
    data['Date']=data['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
    data['close']=data['close'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
    data['open']=data['open'].apply(lambda x: float(x))
    data['rolling_10']=data['close'].rolling(10).sum()/10
    data['rolling_02']=data['close'].rolling(2).sum()/2
    plt.plot(data['Date'],data['close'],label='Close', color='purple')
    plt.plot(data['Date'],data['rolling_10'],label='rolling-10', color='blue')
    plt.plot(data['Date'],data['rolling_02'],label='rolling-02', color='green')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.title('{} Daily'.format(ticker))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```